# Notepad++ finding the opened time of already opened tabs

Tags: notepad++, time, date

I've come across a slew of threads about *adding* the date or *auto-inserting* the date.

But how can I get the *opened time of a tab* that has already been opened?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by checking the date.

Answer (score 5):

Open the `%appdata%\Notepad++\backup` folder to see the list of open tabs.

[image]

Each file has the date/timestamp included in the name. If not, enable the `Date Created` column in that folder to know when a tab was created.